# Python-Using Scrapy to crawl webpages and meet Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl pages under the link below by using Scrapy.
http://nc.mofcom.gov.cn/channel/qytc2017/list.shtml?p_index=210000
when i tried to crawl the next page,
*nc.mofcom.gov.cn/channel/qytc2017/list.shtml?p_index=210000&page=2*
 i find the href to next page was written with Javascript. 
Firstly, I tried to used the code below to find find all possible.

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
    for pageNum in range(1, 10):
        new_url = response.url + "&page=%d" % pageNum
        yield Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_detailpage)
```

because there are only subpages and it will not exceptions;however, i found that 
nc.mofcom.gov.cn/channel/qytc2017/list.shtml?p_index=210000&page=7 and  nc.mofcom.gov.cn/channel/qytc2017/list.shtml?p_index=210000&page=6 share the same content.Indeed, i also notice that some pages have more than 10 subpages,and i am unable to proceed to crawl. Can any one give me some ideas? I don't have 10 reputation and i can present more than 1 links and image, i am really sorry.I really appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to render pages using JavaScript. Splash has seamless integration with Scrapy via [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

Another approach would be to parse the script that contains information about pagination. The script contains the number of pages that are present:

```
var v_PageCount = 6;
```

You could extract the script content using Scrapy and then use for example [js2xml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) library to extract this page count number.